# Start multiple Websocket with different ServerEndpoint

Tags: java, websocket, multiple-instances, endpoint

Is there a way to write a Java Programm which is getting 5 Strings as Argument and then starts 5 WebSocket Instances with these Strings as ServerEndpoint.
If this thought is not good, how can I start multiple Websocket Instances with different ServerEndpoints in Java?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I can answer my own question. Each connetion from a client creates a own ServerEndpoint instance. So there is no need to start multiple websocket instances in one program.